# Can someone use my app without me submitting it to App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, submission

Am developing a iPhone application. We have more then 500 users to review my app.
Without submitting it to the App Store, is it possible to provide permission to all my clients?

Using my Apple developer account I can only add 100 UDIDs. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't without an [enterprise account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

Comment: Is it possible if i got enterprise account, How?

Comment: Yes it is possible using an enterprise account. You can then install the app to as many devices as you want - https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/.

Comment: ... although an enterprise account allows distribution only within your own organisation. Distributing your application to anyone that isn't an employee is a violation of your licence. So you can't use it to distribute to users in any general sense.

Comment: @Tommy The wording, the last time I checked, was that you are allowed to distribute it to users that are "contracted by your organization".  Testers will likely fall into this category.  You are right though, that you are not allowed to *distribute* this app outside of your company.

Answer (score 0):

Users with a jailbroken device can install whichever app they want, without any need of an AppleID, a developer account, etc.